# Webpack-dev-server for frontend + Docker container for backend

Tags: docker, webpack-dev-server, create-react-app

I am not even sure what question to ask to solve my problem but here it goes:

- I am using create-react-app which I believe uses webpack-dev-server to serve my react frontend on localhost:3000.
- I have a docker container with host port 3001 bound to port 80 inside the container serving my backend api and my dev database is also on that container.
- When I want to reach localhost:3001 with an ajax call from my browser, I expect to reach the backend api but it doesn't work.

I know I am missing something and my understanding of the problem is limited. All I am trying to achieve here is have my webpack-dev-server serve my frontend and a docker container serve my api and I want the two to be able to communicate.

Thanks for any help!

```
# docker command when I run my container the volume is the code for my backend so yes my webpack-dev-server runs on host
docker run --rm -d -p 3001:80 -p 3306:3306 -v $(pwd)/app/:/var/www/html/ image:version


# Start from centos-lamp stack image
FROM dockerfiles/centos-lamp

# Place the copied DB file in tmp
COPY ./db.sql /tmp


RUN service mysqld start && \
    echo "CREATE DATABASE testdb" | mysql && \
    mysql testdb < /tmp/db.sql && \
    mysql -e "CREATE USER 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';" && \
    mysql -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'test'@'%';" && \
    mysql -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" && \
    rm -rf /var/www/html/*

EXPOSE 80 3306
```

Comment: Conceptually it's correct, but it'd help to see your docker-compose file (if you have one) or your docker start command. I assume the webpack-dev-server runs on the host and not in a docker image.

Comment: @Stefano Updated my question thx for your help! The volume is the code for my backend so yes my webpack-dev-server runs on host not in a container. What would you suggest to do?

Comment: The image you're using is really old, moreover it's clustering a bunch of services in the same image. I suggest to switch to a different setup

Comment: Okay do you have any suggestions on how to do my new setup?

Comment: sure, start with fetching the mysql image (`docker pull mysql`) and then start building your application based on your needs. Example, if you need django use https://hub.docker.com/_/django/ and so on.

Comment: Okay so 1 container per service? So I would have:

-  A container for my frontend with a mounted volume with my frontend code that starts my webpack-dev-server with an ENTRYPOINT script so that the dev server runs inside my container.

-  A container for mysql which exposes port 3006 for my api to communicate with.

- A container for my api with a mounted volume for all my backend code which can communicate with the db and can be accessed via ajax from the frontend.

Right?

The thing that I am missing is how do I make my containers communicate with each other?

Comment: it sounds right. Concerning the networking issue, I suggest to read: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/#handle-stale-network-endpoints and https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/

Comment: Alright thanks again!